# Style nested text with HTML tag sibling

Tags: html, css

I have two cases I want to style properly:

```
<div class="tabs">
  "Tab 1"
   <a href="/1"="tab">Tab 2</a>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="tabs">
  <a href="/2" class="tab">Tab 1</a>
  "Tab 2" 
</div>
```

I want to have a padding between Tab 1 and Tab 2. How can I specify these properly without putting the text (non-active tab) into its own HTML tag.

Is there a way in CSS to specify like child of type text or so?

So if Tab 1 is active (first case) I want to have padding on the `a` element (Tab 2):

`padding-left: 10px`

If Tab 2 is active (second case) I want to have padding on the `a` element (Tab 1):

`padding-right: 10px`

Comment: You want to have padding between Tab1 and Tab2 ?

Comment: ive not quite understood the requirement can you please ellaborate more

Comment: @VivekGupta Yes, added some notes

Comment: @melwynpawar exactly, also added notes to make this more clear

Comment: "How can I specify these properly without putting the text (non-active tab) into its own HTML tag." - It should be in a suitable text tag anyway.

Comment: The short answer is no.  You either wrap the text in its own `<span>` element (for example) or use JavaScript or jQuery to tease out the details.   With an extra HTML tag, this problem is easily solved. Good mark-up makes good styling possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below css

```
   /* for visited link*/
  a:active {
      padding-left: 10px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may add the following css

```
.tabs{background:#f2f2f2; border:1px solid #ccc; display:inline-block;}
.tabs.active:nth-child(1){padding-left: 10px}
.tabs.active:nth-child(2){padding-right: 10px}
```

and you may apply the active class once the tab is clicked or your anticipated event. In the html below i have added the active class to both the tabs to show the padding applications respectively

```
<div class="tabs active">
tab1
</div>

<div class="tabs active">
tab2
</div>
```